# 'IEnumerable<object>' does not contain a definition for 'ToDataTable' and no accessible extension method 'ToDataTable' accepting a first argument

Tags: c#, epplus

I am trying to import data from Excel to C# using `EPPlus` library. This is my code.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;

var connectionString = "";
string filePath = @"C:\path\to\file.xlsx";
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
{
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    var dataTable = worksheet.Cells.Select(c => c.Value).ToDataTable();

    // code removed for brevity.
}
```

The issue is in line 10, `.ToDataTable()` and the error message is below. How come there is this error message even after I have added its library namespace, `OfficeOpenXml`?

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToDataTable'
> and no accessible extension method 'ToDataTable' accepting a first
> argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why don't you use a `list` instead of a `datatable`?

Comment: I need a datatable to do something later on @HosseinSabziani

Answer (score 1):

The `ToDataTable` method you are trying to call is defined in `ExcelRangeBase` class. So if you call it on `worksheet.Cells` it will work since it's of derived type `ExcelRange`. But after calling `Select` you get `IEnumerable<object>`. There is no extension method `ToDataTable` for `IEnumerable<object>`, that's why you get the error.

You should be able to configure the list of columns with [Mappings](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/ToDataTable#mappings) instead of calling `Select`.